# nesesito ayuda en un checkbox c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

hola buenas estoy queriendo conectar sql server en c# 
pero de forma de checkbox lo esoty haciendo osea tengo un checkbox te pregunta si la authentifcacion es por windows o es por usuario

al momento de llamar un string no me lo reconoce ahi les dejo el codigo antemano gracias

```
        if (tipoAuthentificacion == true) {
        string connectionString0 = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;", cbServer.Text, txtDataBase.Text);

        }
        else
        {
            string connectionString1 = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1}; User Id={2};Password={3};", cbServer.Text, txtDataBase.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);

        }

        string connections = connectionString0 /supuesto error que no reconoce

        try
        {
            CapaNegocio.Conexion Heloper = new Conexion(connections);
            if (Heloper.CheckConnection)
            {
                DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show("Probando conexion exitosa");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show(ex.Message);

        }
```

captura diseño
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es el error? y Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: `/supuesto error que no reconoce` ¿Esta línea está escrita como tal? De ser así, te falta un `/` para poner el comentario y un `;` al final de `connectionString0`.

Comment: es magico que no ande una asignacion a un string. vos estas seguro que la linea anda? que tipo de error tira?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (tipoAuthentificacion == true) 
    {
        string connectionString0 = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;", cbServer.Text, txtDataBase.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        string connectionString1 = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1}; User Id={2};Password={3};", cbServer.Text, txtDataBase.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
    }
    string connections = connectionString0;
```

Este es tu bloque de código, el error es muy sencillo, estas declarando las variables dentro del if, por lo tanto cuando termine las variables se borran, o sea las variables que declaras dentro de las llaves solo se pueden usar ahí ya que son locales, para solucionar el error deberías ponerlo así

```
string connectionString;
if (tipoAuthentificacion == true) 
{
    connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;", cbServer.Text, txtDataBase.Text);
}
else
{
    connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1}; User Id={2};Password={3};", cbServer.Text, txtDataBase.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
}

try
{
    CapaNegocio.Conexion Heloper = new Conexion(connectionString);
    if (Heloper.CheckConnection)
    {
        DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show("Probando conexion exitosa");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que no aconsejaria esto que estas planteando, no se pregunta que tipo de conexion se quiere realizarr desde una interfaz de usuario, el connection string se define en el `app.config` y se toma desde allí directamente.

Si se quiere utilizar usuario y password o autenticacion de windows se usa el notepad se cambiar el .config y se ejecuta la aplicacion, pero el connection string es configuracion.

[Cadenas de conexión y archivos de configuración](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx)

[How to get Connection String from App.Config in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/416198/How-to-get-Connection-String-from-App-Config-in-Cs)

analiza los artículo para ver donde defines el connection string y como lo recuperas usando la clase `ConfigurationManager`

Comment: Tu comentario esta bien, pero no es lo que esta preguntando OP.. y tampoco se si no recomendaria, todo depende para que lo uses.. si es un programa para vos en tu pc, no lo harias?

Comment: no, no lo haria porque definir el conection string en codigo si se puede configurar y es tan simple como editar con el notepad. Ademas si es para probar la conexion creo un archivo .udl que para eso existe